"Error: Expected Expression" when using logic short circuits
I have this programming assignment in C that asks to reverse a string without using  if-else statements, ternary operators, or loops/switches so that we have to use recursion and logic short circuits to implement the tasks.
Here's the function I've implemented to reverse a given string:
void reverse(char* str, int start, int end)
{
    ((start >= end) && (return));
    
    char tmp = str[start];
    str[start] = str[end];
    str[end] = tmp;
    
    reverse(str, start + 1, end - 1);
}

However, the C compiler complains about the return statement and outputs "Error: Expected Expression".
How should I implement the return statement whenever (start >= end) evaluates to true?

Welcome to SO. Using recursion without if to detect the termination condition is just one of those weird useless BS that only teachers can come up with. That said, your compiler is right. && operator requires an expression on both sides and return is not an expression. But a function call is an expression (as long as the function returns a value)

Is the goal of the assignment to turn students into worse programmers than they were before the assignment? ...

Just write while(start >= end) return ;. Look ma, no if!

God damn it... Thanks anyways for the response.

Unfortunately we're not allowed to use loops either.

So the task is to guess what's on the teacher's mind? About as meaningful as the teacher thinking of a number between 1 and 100 and have the students guess until they get the right one. I can write some dirty hack answer to this with setjmp or whatever, but it won't do you no good.

Re “Unfortunately we're not allowed to use loops either”: Edit the question to state all of the requirements.

Yep I've made the edit to the problem statement, thanks.

No sane programmer would ever do this. But real world rules don't seem to be valid in some programming courses.
Your compiler is right that you cannot use return with a logical AND operator.
You need an expressions for this and return is not an expression.
What you can do is call a function instead. As long as it has a return value, it is an expression.
If you are not allowed to change signature of your reverse function, you need to introduce a helper function:
bool crazy_assignment_helper(char *str, int start, int end)
{
  // Assume we are called with valid arguments.
  // swap first and last character
  char tmp = str[start];
  str[start] = str[end];
  str[end] = tmp;

  // Continue with inner part if we are not done yet.
  return ((start+1) < (end-1)) && crazy_assignment_helper(str, start+1, end-1);
}

void reverse(char *str, int start, int end)
{
  (void)crazy_assignment_helper(str, start, end);
}

This assumes, the initial call is made using valid values.
I hope, the teacher will tell you afterwards, that you should never ever use such code in a real project in your job.

My head is spinning in circles now... I'll take a closer look at this, thanks.

((start+1) < (end-1)) && (reverse(str, start+1, end-1),1); Unchanged func. signature... No "helper" needed. ... Why not make it really perverse?

@Fe2O3 that was copy&paste error. We do need the helper as void function would not be suitable for an expression

@Gerhardh Here: https://godbolt.org/z/o99e8jY58

Wait why do you need the ",1"? I'm so confused

@RobertSun because Fe203 uses the original void revers() function. void is not an expression. Using comma operator ,1 you make it an expression that you can use on the right side of && operator. His version is just meant to add even more BS than your teacher already did.

@RobertSun Pay special attention to the parentheses surrounding the 2nd expression. The comma is C's "comma operator". The entire "expression" combines a void function call (not a valid expression on its own) with 1 (a valid "expression" in C). So, the compiler "sees", inside the parentheses, a function call followed by an expression and is satisfied that there IS an rvalue that IS the value of ( expression ). (C can be cryptic. Use this knowledge wisely, and, by all means, avoid the Dark Side, Luke!)

This should work with the artificial requirements:
int swap (char* a, char* b)
{
  char tmp = *a;
  *a = *b;
  *b = tmp;
  return 1;    
}

int reverse (char* str, int start, int end)
{
  str[start]!='\0' && 
  start<end  && 
  swap(&str[start], &str[end]) && 
  reverse(str, start+1, end-1);
  return 1;
}

That is:

No conditional statements, conditional ?: operator or loops, so we have to use an obfuscation trick with the && operator, which only evaluates the right operand in case the left one is true. Meaning the function is a long chain of && conditions.

str[start]!='\0' checks for null termination.

start<end is the "loop condition", we should keep calling the function recursively and add +1 to start and -1 to end until they meet in the middle.

swap is a plain old variable swap function. It has to return 1 to keep && happy.

Same deal with the recursive reverse call, has to return something, doesn't really matter what. In the call, we do the +1 and -1 on start and end respectively.
(If we want to keep the return type of void reverse then we could as well do (reverse(str, start+1, end-1),1))


Full example:
#include <stdio.h>

int swap (char* a, char* b)
{
  char tmp = *a;
  *a = *b;
  *b = tmp;
  return 1;    
}

int reverse (char* str, int start, int end)
{
  str[start]!='\0' && 
  start<end  && 
  swap(&str[start], &str[end]) && 
  reverse(str, start+1, end-1);
  return 1;
}

int main()
{
  char str[] = "hello world";
  puts(str);
  reverse(str, 0, sizeof(str) - 2); // size -1 for null term, then -1 again to point at last letter
  puts(str);
}

Output:
hello world
dlrow olleh


This answer could contribute something new if it explained that , 0 ), instead of , 1 ), would work just as well... Just a suggestion...

@Fe2O3 I kind of did here: "has to return something, doesn't really matter what". As for contributing something new, I already had this typed down shortly after responding to the OP in comments below the question, but I'm at work and was distracted for an hour. When I came back, Gerhardh had made a very similar program, it turned out. And so he wins the FGITW reward, but since I had already coded this I might as well post it...

In that case: void swap() could use the same "trick/technique" to drive home the concept... Just a suggestion...

For better obfuscation maybe some mix of && and || might be used. :)

@Gerhardh Or the classic ??!??! wtf operator.

You almost got there! However, as explained by @Gerhardh, return is not an expression and cannot be used as one.
Please disregard disparaging commentary regarding this assigned challenge with its artificial constraints. This exercise is to force you to think and to use the information that (it is hoped) you have already been exposed to (or to explore on your own the meaning and use of C's "operators" laid out in the documentation's "Precedence Table".)
The VG code presented by @Gerhardh demonstrates one perfectly valid approach, but necessitates using a "helper function" to comply with the (presumed) constraint of an unalterable function signature.
The code below is slightly more compact, and demonstrates an alternative solution. This code does not require a "helper" function.
#include <stdio.h>

void reverse( char *str, int iLeft, int iRght ) {
    char tmp = str[ iLeft ];
    str[ iLeft ] = str[ iRght ];
    str[ iRght ] = tmp;

    // compulsory(!) explanatory comment goes here
    ( ++iLeft >= --iRght ) || ( reverse( str, iLeft, iRght ), 0 );
}

int main( void ) {
    char foo[] = "madam. in Eden i'm adam";

    puts( foo );
    reverse( foo, 0, sizeof foo - 2 );
    puts( foo );
    reverse( foo, 0, sizeof foo - 2 );
    puts( foo );

    return 0;
}

It (trivially) uses pre-increment and pre-decrement instead of adding or subtracting 1 twice. (The compiler may optimise both to equivalent machine code. This merely demonstrates an alternative.)
This logic uses >= and then || instead of < and &&.
Read this as "done OR continue" instead of "not done AND continue".
The expression on the right of || is made up of two sequential statements separated by C's "comma operator". The first of these is a call to a void function so is not an expression as it has no value returned. The second "expression" is the constant 0 that is a value; and is used as the value of the entire expression enclosed by the parentheses. In this use, the constant used is irrelevant (could be 42). The compiler is satisfied that there is an expression after the ||, so all is well in the world.

Anecdote: Years ago, I "inherited" some "Oracle Forms" code that was used as a "forms based" interface to a large SQL database. The values of UI "controls" affected the particulars of SQL "SELECT" statements (and more) to interact with the database engine.
Tasked with adding a fifth "radio button" to one "form" (and the supporting code-behind-the-form), I found FOUR blocks of repetitious, discretely altered (copy/paste/adapt) code, each spanning about 35 lines. Which of the four executed was determined by their enclosing if/else if conditionals that were 'true' for one of the 4 existing "radio buttons" selected.
Applying a technique very much like shown here ("gating" the appropriate clause of the "WHERE" segment of the "SELECT" statement), all 4 instances could be merged into a single (more capable) instance, and the 5th added by adding only one line of code to that instance.
Don't be put off striving to write the best code that you can. And, importantly, use clear(!), proximate comments to explain non-obvious operations.
